# Prevent going back or closing an app

Tags: java, android, performance, android-fragments

I have a chat app and I have created an activity to delete the account if the user wants to delete his account, and I did so successfully without problems but my problem is that I want to move user to the registration activity, but the problem is that the user can go back to delete account activity, the delete feature is consisted from activity and within a fragment.

I try to use `getActivity().finish()`, But when pressed back button it takes back to the delete activity with no fragment!

On other hands, I think to close the app but some people say to me that this is an ugly solution.

Comment: Simplify your life: after a user deletes his/her account, return to the login/registration screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing The Activity Should Always Be Done By Activity Itself So 
It's always good to use interface to interact from Fragment to Activity as per the docs: [Communicating with Activity from Fragment](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating).

**`Activity`**:-

```
public class DeleteAccountActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DeleteUserFragment.DeleteCompletedCallback {

   public void onDeleteCompleted() {
      Intent intent = new Intent(DeleteAccountActivity.this,RegisterAccountActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
      finish();
   }       
}
```

**`Fragment`**:-

```
public class DeleteUserFragment extends Fragment {
   private DeleteCompletedCallback deleteCompletedCallback;//Creating A Callback For Interaction With Activity In The Fragtment.

   @Override
   public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
     super.onAttach(activity);
     deleteCompletedCallback = (DeleteCompletedCallback) activity;
   }

   public interface DeleteCompletedCallback{//Making The Interface To Be Implemented In The Activity.
       void onDeleteCompleted();
   }        
  }
}
```

Write These Line After User Is Successfully Deleted, Maybe Something Like This:-

```
if(isUserDeleted())
{
 if(deleteCompletedCallback != null)
    {
      deleteCompletedCallback.onDeleteCompleted();
    }
}
```